# How to show that every prime ideal 0f R contains a unique prime of $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field with the ring of integers of $R$. How to show that every prime ideal of $R$ contains a unique prime of $\mathbb{Z}$.

I have no idea, could you please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the condition *nonzero*, by the way:  $(0)$ is prime in $R$ also.

Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be prime in $R$.  Then $\mathfrak{p}$ contains at most one prime of $\mathbb{Z}$, since if it contained two primes of $\mathbb{Z}$, it would have to contain $1$ (some linear combination of two relatively prime numbers is $1$).

On the other hand, $\mathfrak{p}$ must contain some nonzero element $n$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ (think about the minimal polynomial for some element of $\mathfrak{p}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$; the constant term must be in $\mathfrak{p}$).  Now factor $n$ into primes in $\mathbb{Z}$; by primality of $\mathfrak{p}$ one of these primes must be contained in $\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: Excuse me. Why must the constant term be in $p$?

Comment: @ElieBergman the element $a$ of the ideal is a root. Thus if the polynomial is $\sum_{i=0}^k b_i X^i $ then $b_0 =-  \sum_{i=1}^k b_i a^i =  a (-  \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} b_i a^{i-1} )$.